# Got a stuck with windows phone 7 emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-7-emulator

When i am running my windows phone application its giving an error of "**The object invoked is disconnected from its client**"

Comment: I have the same problem, but not everytime...

Comment: I have a different problem. Every time.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess you should check your machine's requirements,  the minimum requirement to urn the emulator 2GB RAM. You Might get lucky to run the emulator with less RAM but it certainly will come back to haunt you.

Answer (score 1):

usually this happen when your visual studio get "disconnected" from the emulator.